# Truncate decimals after float point in python without rounding

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm trying to find a function in python that does something like

```
a = 9.43257
b = 32.8

func(a, 3)# 9.432
func(b, 4)# 32.8000
```

I've tried several things like `round()` and `".2f"` , but these methods round up the number , which i don't need.

Comment: there's `math.floor()` which is round down

Comment: Beware: this question is not as well-defined as you might think. After `b = 32.799999999999997`, what would you want `func(b, 4)` to give?

Comment: Or alternatively, what would you want `func(1.5714, 4)`  to give? (The accepted answer gives `1.5713`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function

```
def func(f, n):
    return math.trunc(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

a = 9.43257
b = 32.8

func(a, 3)# 9.432
func(b, 4)# 32.8
```

Comment: oh i forgot that there cannot be zeros in the end of a float :-)

Comment: Please check now

Comment: @baronsec please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you would want this but it seems like you are asking for truncate from python's math

```
import math

def truncate(number, decimals=0):
    factor = 10.0 ** decimals
    return math.trunc(number * factor) / factor
truncate(12.3456, 2)
# Returns: 12.34
```

Comment: Did you try executing this code?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Excellent point.

Answer (score 0):

```
def truncate_float(n, places):
    if len(str(n).split(".")[1]) == places:
        return n
    else:
        return int(n * (10 ** places)) / 10 ** places
```

worked for me the best as it gives the correct answer(thanks to @MarkDickinson for showing the problem)